# Fabric.js flipX and flipY don't seem to work

Tags: fabricjs

I can't flip a rectangle to save my life in Fabric.js, even using the code straight from the tutorials here - http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1/#objects.  If someone could please take a look at this fiddle and let me know what I'm doing wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.

http://jsfiddle.net/thardy/E4Vcr/

```
rect.set('angle', 15).set('flipY', true); // doesn't work
canvas.renderAll(); // this wasn't in the tutorial, but I'm pretty sure it's needed
```

Is this a bug in v1.4.0?

Comment: Hm, yes, looks like a regression :/ Doesn't work with `rect` and `circle`. Works with triangle, line, polygon, image, text. Please file a ticket on github.

Comment: Issue submitted - https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1063

Comment: This appears to be a misunderstanding of how flipX and flipY are supposed to work.  I think they are actually working in fabricjs.  I've updated my fiddle above to more clearly display why I didn't think they were working.  Perhaps this will be helpful to someone in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a misunderstanding of how flipX and flipY are supposed to work. I think they are actually working in fabricjs. I've updated my fiddle above to more clearly display why I didn't think they were working. Perhaps this will be helpful to someone in the future