# FlipX or FlipY after rotation issue

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to make the 'Flip' options function similar to that of any visual editor (i.e. Photoshop, MS Word), where the flip command takes into account any rotation that a user may have made.

I've played around with getting the current rotation and then applying the negative value when rotated, but this is still buggy.

```
group.toggle('flipY');
var angle = group.get('angle')
var negangle = 0 - angle;
group.set("angle", negangle);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hellohudson/2gkjb5za/
(Thanks to [Tim Hardy's initial fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670771/fabric-js-flipx-and-flipy-dont-seem-to-work) that i've tweaked.)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! The location is changing because the default origin of your group object is the top left corner. By setting both `originX` and `originY` of your group object to `center`, the group's center will be used for positioning which shouldn't change during flips. See more on origins here: [Origins Documentation](http://fabricjs.com/test/misc/origin.html)

Also, don't forget to call `setCoords()` any time you change properties like `flipX` and `flipY` so that the control positions recalculate.

http://jsfiddle.net/melchiar/wok0n3yc/